# Youtube python: get thumbnail

Tags: python, youtube, thumbnails

Is there a simple way to get the default thumbnail from a youtube entry object gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntry?

I tried entry.media.thumbnail, but that gives me four thumbnail objects. Can I always trust that there are four? Can I know which is the default thumbnail that would also appears on the youtube search page? And how would I get that one? Or do I have to alter one of the other ones?

When I know the video_id I use:

http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/{{video_id}}/default.jpg

so, it would also be helpful to get the video_id.

Do I really have to parse one of the url's to get at the video_id ? It seems strange that they don't provide this information directly.

Answer (score 6):

You can put video id to a special url:

```
thumnail_url = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/%s/0.jpg" % video_id
```

Or you can create template filter: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2234/

Comment: clean solution. In my case urls are inside a model. So wrote a property to return the thumbnail.

Answer (score 3):

This is a how to get the default thumbnail from a `gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntry` object:

```
import gdata.youtube.service

service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
feed_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed?v=2'
feed = service.GetYouTubeVideoFeed(feed_url)
entry = feed.entry[0] # pick most viewed video as sample entry

thumbnail = entry.media.thumbnail[0].url
    # will be an URL like: 'http://i.ytimg.com/vi/%(video_id)s/default.jpg'
    # when querying YouTube API version 2 ('?v=2' at the end of feed URL)
```

You cannot trust that there are always 4 thumbnails (but this is *almost always* the case). The default thumbnail is the first one in the list of thumbnails.

You can also get the video URL with `entry.id.text` and extract the actual video ID from end, but you cannot assume that a fixed pattern such as `'http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/%(video_id)s/default.jpg'` will give you the thumbnail URL. You should get the thumbnail URLs from the video entry.

**EDIT:** To get the "default.jpg" thumbnail first in the list of thumbnails, you should query version 2 of the YouTube API (by appending an extra "?v=2" parameter to the feed URL). I updated the example to make this clear.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is correct:

In youtube search for "Try to watch without laughing or grinning! LOL!"

it shows two cats in two cups.

This is the same as:

http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/I_6UTGzgOnU/default.jpg

but it is not the same as the first thumbnail, which is:

http://i.ytimg.com/vi/I_6UTGzgOnU/2.jpg

Comment: Ah, I see about the version. Unfortunately,  don't specify the url (or version) at all. I use youtube's Python API:

yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()

query = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeVideoQuery()
   .
   
   ...add search terms to query and other query parameters.
   
   .
 
 
feed = yt_service.YouTubeQuery(query)


I don't see a way to tell it what version to use. Do you happen to know?

Comment: In order to include the version parameter "v=2" and comply with the new API, you'll have to migrate your current `query.ToUri()` according to http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/youtube/2.0/migration.html (unfortunately, as stated in that doc, the Python YouTube API client hasn't been updated to version 2 yet). Then, get the resulting XML with: `xml = service.Query(uri).ToString()`. And finally, get the feed with `feed = gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoFeedFromString(xml)`. The rest, you know. PS: Not having an up-to-date Python client to query YouTube really sucks! :P

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to get high quality thumbnail is:

```
"https://img.youtube.com/vi/[vid_id]/maxresdefault.jpg"
```

and you can find the video id as showing blew:

```
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[this is video id]"
```

**Finally:**

```
url = ....
imgUrl = f"https://img.youtube.com/vi/{url[url.find('watch?v='):]}/maxresdefault.jpg"
```